# Problema Typescript Error Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: ionic, variables, object

Estoy tratando de enviar una informacion con ajax que es la siguiente

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Proveedor1Provider } from '../../providers/proveedor1/proveedor1';
import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    usuarios="";

    constructor(public toastCtrl: ToastController,
          public navCtrl: NavController,
          public provedor: Proveedor1Provider,
          public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {}

    openNavDetailsPage(item) {
        this.navCtrl.push(AboutPage, { item: item });
    }
    presentToast(val) {
        const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
         message: 'The character '+val+' is not registered',
         duration: 3000
        });
        toast.present();
    }
    getItems(ev) {

        let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content: 'Please wait...'
        });
        var val = ev.target.value;
        if(val.length > 1){
            loading.present();
            this.provedor.obtenerDatos(val)
            .subscribe(
                (data)=> {if(data != undefined){this.usuarios = data;}else{this.presentToast(val);this.usuarios = '';}},
                (error)=> {console.log(error);},
                ()=>{loading.dismiss();}
                )
        }
    }
}
```

El error que me da es que this.usuarios en la parte de

```
(data)=> {
  if(data != undefined){this.usuarios = data;} 
  else{this.presentToast(val);this.usuarios = '';}}
```

es el siguiente

> Typescript Error: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Answer (score 0):

Debe ser por que data es un Array Object u Object, puedes transformarlo con data.toString() o verificar sus valores con `console.log();`

una forma de acceder a datos en un array json es con [] Ej:

`data[0][0]['nombre_campo'];`

Answer (score 0):

El error te sale porque Typescript (el compilador) está asumiendo que data no es un String. Eso significa que `this.provedor.obtenerDatos(val)` (hay una errata, supongo que es prove**e**dor) devuelve un Observable donde T no es un string.

Tendrás que comprobar la firma de ese método para solucionar el problema.